# Knockout components and other viewModels coexistence

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I've learnt that after registering a knockout component, one should call `ko.applyBindings()` without argument. However, when defining another viewModel without components, let's call it `vm`, one should call `ko.applyBindings(new vm())`. Now when I try to use both in parallel, I get an error

```
You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
```

See also [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tobiasfeil/2ja3qgyx/6/)

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Register the component first, and then call `applyBindings` with your main viewmodel once. Knockout will take care of creating a new viewmodel instance for your component. https://jsfiddle.net/734z80gr/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that makes sense. Glad to see it works like this. Unfortunately, I can't quite do it like that, because I'm working in a project where first I define and use my own component, and later, another html page is loaded via `$.load` that has a script tag where a viewModel is defined, and `applyBindings` is called on that viewModel. How can I keep those from conflicting? Because I have to call `applyBindings` first or else I can't use my component

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was that you cannot call `applyBindings` without a second argument (aka, an HTML element that the bindings are scoped under), twice. For my component, I would have gladly provided a second argument, namely the component itself, but this exists nowhere in the docs, all you can find is `applyBindings()` without any argument. So, by trial and error, I found that

```
ko.applyBindings(null, document.getElementById('id'))
```

with `id` being the id of the component HTML element, works.